# MongoDB pull array element from a collection

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb, pull

I have a mongodb object as follows:

```
array (
  '_id' => new MongoId("4cc97fb0247ae8747ec5fefb"),
  'posts' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'comment' => 'Eamorr',
      'fromUname' => 'Eamorr',
      'time' => 1288273840,
      'UTC' => '2010-10-28T14:50:40+01:00',
      'ip' => '127.0.0.1',
      'id' => '123lasdfiqwoei28asdf',
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      'comment' => 'Hello',
      'fromUname' => 'Eamorr',
      'time' => 1288277023,
      'UTC' => '2010-10-28T15:43:43+01:00',
      'ip' => '127.0.0.1',
      'id' => 'qopqwier982389qwfa',
    ),
    2 => 
    array (
      'comment' => 'Hello',
      'fromUname' => 'Anonymous',
      'time' => 1288283506,
      'UTC' => '2010-10-28T17:31:46+01:00',
      'ip' => '127.0.0.1',
      'id' => 'ioqwoeias892398wrf',
    ),
    /////
    //Want to remove element 3:
    /////
    3 => 
    array (
      'comment' => 'asdfasadf',
      'fromUname' => 'Anonymous',
      'time' => 1288283864,
      'UTC' => '2010-10-28T17:37:44+01:00',
      'ip' => '127.0.0.1',
      'id' => 'wwwwwiasdfn234oiasf',
    ),
    4 => 
    array (
      'comment' => 'asdfasdfasdf',
      'fromUname' => 'Anonymous',
      'time' => 1288284076,
      'UTC' => '2010-10-28T17:41:16+01:00',
      'ip' => '127.0.0.1',
      'id' => '290qwefoiqweproiqwerpq',
    ),
    5 => 
    array (
      'comment' => 'ASDF',
      'fromUname' => 'Eamorr',
      'time' => 1288284331,
      'UTC' => '2010-10-28T17:45:31+01:00',
      'ip' => '127.0.0.1',
      'id' => 'eioqw8923892hasdf',
    ),
    6 => 
    array (
      'comment' => 'ASDF2',
      'fromUname' => 'Eamorr',
      'time' => 1288284370,
      'UTC' => '2010-10-28T17:46:10+01:00',
      'ip' => '127.0.0.1',
      'id' => '23oaiofsaij234',
    ),
  ),
  'uname' => 'Eamorr',
)
```

Now, I am writing some PHP code to remove posts[x]. I'm trying to use $pull to remove the array element.

I have an 'id' 'wwwwwiasdfn234oiasf' (array element 3) and I want to remove this *entire* array element, leaving just 6 elements in the 'posts' array.

I've tried googling and looking up the documentation to no avail... I still can't get the hang of the mongodb syntax.

I'm doing all this in PHP, but any language will do I should be able to do the translation.

Many thanks in advance,

Solution (in PHP):

```
$uname=whatever
$id=whatever
$mongo=new Mongo();
$walls=$mongo->people->walls;
$walls->update(array('uname'=>$uname),array('$pull'=>array('posts'=>array('id'=>$id))));
```

Comment: Be careful about what type of `$id` you pass on to MongoDB. The following could save you a few times: `$id = new MongoId($id);`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here's how to do it using the MongoDB shell. You should be able to translate it into PHP.

A pull operation consists of the `$pull` modifier, a **field selector** and a **value expression**.

```
{ $pull: { fieldSelector: valueExpression } }
```

In your case the field selector is `posts`, since that's the array you want to update. The value expression, in plain English, is

> where the `id` of the post equals "wwwwwiasdfn234oiasf"

This translates to `{ id: "wwwwwiasdfn234oiasf" }`. If we combine all of this, you'll get the following `$pull` statement, which will remove the desired item from the array:

```
{ $pull: { posts: { id: "wwwwwiasdfn234oiasf" } } }
```