# MongoDB, array storage and Object querying

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb, object

I am new to MongoDb and I've made a simple PHP filtering application (similar to TAGS)

I Have a collection which is called "Filters"

Inside of it, each record looks like this:

```
    "_id" : ObjectId("5274da3e040b61fa15000001"),
"activation" : 1,
"and_or" : "",
"description" : "",
"id" : 13,
"order_id" : 2,
"slug" : [
    "apple",
    "orange",
    "banana"
],
"title" : "Sample"
```

I take those values from a PHP form and insert them like a record.

**The problem is**
When I try to remove **"orange"** from **slug**, the array breaks and turns into an Object

```
"slug" : {
    "0" : "apple",
    "2" : "banana"
},
```

And I can no longer query it like this, as it returns **NULL**

> db.filters.find({slug: "apple"})

```
null
```

I assume that when an array's index is numerically correct, (1, 2, 3, 4) then Mongo will recognize it as an array, otherwise it stores it as an object as custom index is used.

Unfortunately, I cannot change the indexes of the array because they are linked in other documents.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Or maybe there is a away of actually searching inside and Object in MongoDB and returning the key?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4058748/mongodb-pull-array-element-from-a-collection might help

Comment: How exactly do you "remove orange from slug"?

Comment: by submitting the form with 2 inputs form[slug][0] = apple and form[slug][2] = Banana... without problem in php

Answer (score 1):

You are getting null because you might be removing that document using remove method in php.
Instead you need to update slug to array with only apple as its element

db.collection.update($array);